# get cost of ingredients in a recipe

Tags: python, list, function

I am writing a short program to calculate the costs of the ingredients in a recipe. I have created a list with name, qty purchased, purchase price, and units that will be used to calculate the costs. I have a function to calculate the individual cost of each ingredient which should be passed to main function that will print a statement showing the name of ingredient and the cost of the quantity of units used in the recipe.
My problem is when I print the statement it is not picking up the correct information.

```
    compute_ingredient_cost(recipe_ingredients)
    unit_qty = 0
    for item in recipe_ingredients:
        print(f"The cost of {item[0]} is ${item[2]:.2f} for {unit_qty} units.")
    print()

def compute_ingredient_cost(recipe_ingredients):
    ingredient_cost =[]
    for item in recipe_ingredients:
        unit_qty = input(f"Enter the qty of {item[0]} used: ")
        ingredient_cost = float(COST) / float(QTY) * float(unit_qty)
        item.append(ingredient_cost)
    print()
    return ingredient_cost
```

When I run the program, this is what I get:

```
Enter the qty of ing1 used: 25
Enter the qty of ing2 used: 20
Enter the qty of ing3 used: 15
Enter the qty of ing4 used: 10

The cost of ing1 is $6.25 for 0 units.
The cost of ing2 is $6.25 for 0 units.
The cost of ing3 is $7.25 for 0 units.
The cost of ing4 is $3.50 for 0 units.
```

It is showing the total purchase price for the ingredients instead of the cost of ingredients used, and shows 0 for the units used. Can someone tell me how to fix this? Please.

Comment: In function `compute_ingredient_cost` you start with `ingredient_cost ` as a list, which you assign to a float then append `ingredient_cost` to `item`, your for loop iterator.  Confusing.

Comment: This program is all over the place. Function defined after it's used. Using a list instead of dict for properties like price, name etc. Using local variables with same name as global. Would start from scratch

Comment: Sorry. I’m really new at this. This is not the entire code. The compute_ingredient_cost function is defined in the main function. That is why it looks like is defined after it is used. I only posted the part I am having a problem with hoping for some direction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem and came up with this code:

```
ingridients = [{"name": "ing1", "qty_purchased": 10, "purchase_price": 100},
                {"name": "ing2", "qty_purchased": 20, "purchase_price": 100},
                {"name": "ing3", "qty_purchased": 30, "purchase_price": 90},
                {"name": "ing4", "qty_purchased": 40, "purchase_price": 40}]

for item in ingridients:
    print(item)
    
print()

def compute_ingr_cost(recipe_ingr):
    ingr_used = []
    for item in recipe_ingr:
        unit_qty = input(f"Enter the qty of {item['name']} used: ")
        ingr_cost = float(item['purchase_price']) / float(item['qty_purchased']) * float(unit_qty)
        ingr_used.append({"name": item['name'], "ingredient_cost": ingr_cost, "ingredient_qty": unit_qty})
    return(ingr_used)

ingr_used = compute_ingr_cost(ingridients)

for item in ingr_used:
    print(f"The cost of {item['name']} is ${item['ingredient_cost']:.2f} for {item['ingredient_qty']} units.")
```

I propose to use a list of dictionaries to store the ingredients data.
Then the function uses user input to get the number of ingredients used in the recipe, calculates cost of these ingredients and returns another list of dictionaries with the data for final input (quantity of ingridients used, their price and names).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try to help me. I Understand what you are saying. Is it really necessary to use a dictionary? I already have a list created, and was hoping that I could use the list instead of creating a dictionary. Would it help for me to post all the program so that you can see what I have? Your dictionary is very close to my list. But I made a few changes and am still not getting the desired result.

Comment: ```NAME = 0
QTY = 1
COST = 2
UNIT = 3

def main():

    product_type = input("What is the product name? ")
    print()

    recipe_ingredients = [
        ['ing1', 4 , 6.25, 114 ],
        ['ing2', 4 , 6.25, 114 ],
        ['ing3', 4 , 7.25, 114 ],
        ['ing4', 4 , 3.50, 114 ]
    ]

    print("The recipe ingredients are: ")    
    for item in recipe_ingredients:
        print(item[0])
    print()

   ```

Comment: ``` compute_ingredient_cost(recipe_ingredients)
    unit_qty = 0
    for item in recipe_ingredients:
        print(f"The cost of {item[0]} is ${item[2]:.2f} for {unit_qty} units.")
    print()

def compute_ingredient_cost(recipe_ingredients):
    ingredient_cost =[]
    for item in recipe_ingredients:
        unit_qty = input(f"Enter the qty of {item[0]} used: ")
        ingredient_cost = float(COST) / float(QTY) * float(unit_qty)
        item.append(ingredient_cost)
    print()
    return ingredient_cost

main()```

Comment: It is better to use dictionary, because the code is more readable. With list you have to remember what information you store in each position.
This expression:

`ingredient_cost = float(COST) / float(QTY) * float(unit_qty)`
Doesn't make any sense, as you dividing 2 by 1 (this variables are assigned at the top of your code). So instead of them you need to right something like this:

`ingredient_cost = float(item[COST]) / float(item[QTY]) * float(unit_qty)`
This will get you the cost of the ingredient.

Comment: I actually had 4 items in the list: name, quantity_purchased, purchase_price, units (which was a smaller portion of the quantity purchased and would be used to show the amount of ingredient used in the recipe, and to calculate the cost of ingredient used).  After looking at your code, I understood that I did not need the quantity_purchased, as the calculation only used the unit_qty. With your example, I was able to get my code working. Thank you. I am still very new at this, and the parameters, arguments, and variable names are still confusing to me. Thank you so much for taking time to help.